# Declare custom mimeType for NFC intent

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to have a custom mimeType for an NDEF_DISCOVERED?

```
        <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I'd like to have a custom mimeType, for example

```
<data android:mimeType="customType" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NFC/WebBeam), I use:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.commonsware.sample.webbeam"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you know perhaps why with the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent the app relaunches? Is it possible to prevent this behavior?

Comment: @hermann: "Do you know perhaps why with the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent the app relaunches?" -- it just calls `startActivity()`. "Is it possible to prevent this behavior?" -- use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your `<activity>`.

Comment: However this prevents me from displaying the data from the NFC tag.

Comment: @hermann: No, it doesn't. Your `Intent` from the NFC tag is delivered to `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: It's like you were expecting this comment. Hahah, thanks a lot.

Comment: @hermann: No, just been down that road before. Besides, it's demonstrated in the sample app.

Comment: thanks. How do you handle activity state changes such as when the screen orientation changes or a change between fragments ( tabbed application ) ? The NDEF data that is displayed is then not recovered.

Comment: @hermann: The same way you handle anything else in a configuration change, such as putting the data in the `Bundle` supplied to `onSaveInstanceState()`.